# html 5 validation is not working in jquery ui dialog box

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a dialog box with some form fields.When I click on the submit button inside this dialog box the form is not validating using HTML5 attributes.But I can validate the form using Jquery validate plugin.But I need to do HTML5 native validation on button click, this is not working.

## My code is as below.

```
$("#popup").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "View/Edit Screen",
    dialogClass: "pop-content pop-header-colr pop-button pop-float",
    width: 800,
    height: 650,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    show: 'clip',
    buttons: {
        'SUBMIT': function () {
            var accs_lvl = $('#accs_lvl').val();
            alert("accs_lvl " + accs_lvl);
            var curr_page = $('#curr_page').val();
            alert("curr_page " + curr_page);
            if (accs_lvl == 1 || (curr_page == 'cis' && accs_lvl == 6)) {
                var url_path = 'url_path';
                var args = {
                    "formData": JSON.stringify(ConvertFormToJSON('#pop_up_form')),
                        "bkup_doc_path": $('#bkup_doc_proof').val(),
                        "lttr_doc_path": $('#lttr_doc').val()
                };
            }
            if (accs_lvl == 2 || accs_lvl == 3 || ((curr_page == 'ofac' || curr_page == 'fla') && accs_lvl == 6)) {
                var url_path = 'url_path';
                var args = {
                    "chkReqIDs": $('#chk_req_id').val(),
                        "actionCode": $('#change_status').val(),
                        "notes": $('#reason_notes').val()
                };
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: url_path,
                type: 'GET',
                data: args,
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert("success"); 
                    $('#popup').dialog('close');
                    $("#cmn_sbmt").click();
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
});
```

Am I missing some thing here to do html5 native validation. Can any one please help me out resolve this.

Your timely help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide your form markup. Which HTML5 validation attributes are you trying to use that are not working?

Comment: Attributes like "required"  ,

Comment: Thanks for the response.Attributes like "required"  , "pattern". Atleast the "required" attribute should be worked.I am populating the form dynamically inside the dialog box. When I click on submit button the form is not validating using html5 attributes like "required" and "pattern" etc...

Comment: Again, this is where we'd need to see your form markup. If you're just placing inputs into a <div> or something inside a jQ UI Dialog, that's not an actual <form> element. For HTML5 validation to occur, you need to be submitting a form with the inputs inside or, as was added in HTML5, by setting their "form" attribute. You could also, within your custom submit function, check the validity.valid property for your inputs. The key is unless you're submitting an actual <form>, the browser won't automatically check/enforce the HTML5 validation attributes.